# Address bar keeps popping down in mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mobile-safari

I am having trouble in mobile Safari. I have a link that when clicked (or tapped) fires some Javascript but does not navigate to a new page (`onclick="return false"`). The link is performing the way that I want but when it is tapped the address bar in mobile safari pops down for a second giving the impression that one is navigating somewhere. I need a way to prevent this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I have found is to remove the href's from the links in general via javascript.